# How to change the selection of rows by data in the Azure data factory data preview?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In a data flow of a Azure Data Factory pipeline I want to preview a specific period of rows in the data preview tab. Whenever I refresh the data preview I see for example data of a year ago, while I want to see the data of the last few weeks. I know the data is in there. Is there a way you can select the data from only the last few weeks by for example using the Date column or something else?

If I data preview I see the following data:
[image]

It is weird because whenever in a different data flow I again connect to this data I see a complete different TimeStamp. I guess data preview just takes a random sample of the complete data. But can you somehow specify what period of data you want to preview?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using filter transformation. Do Data Preview on your filter, once your done you can just remove it

[image]

[image]

Comment: This does not work. The filter1 works with the input data of source1. If the source data doesn't contain the data of last weeks, then it won't be visible when you filter on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the debug settings in dataflow, so that data preview will happen only on the small dataset instead of the entire dataset.

- Select **debug settings** in dataflow
- click the source for source1 as **sample file**.
- Use the sample file which has only filtered data.

[image: gif1]

- This will make sure that while previewing data, it uses the required data and when executing it uses the whole source dataset.